# Solution to youtube z-index using old embed code?

Tags: html, youtube

When using the old embed code you might experience the overlapping player over your popups or any divs. There are quite a few solutions out there but mostly it's for the iframe code of Youtube. But what about the old embed code?

I've had a hard time finding out the solution for this. I want your opinion if you have also used the same answer I did for this. Let me know if I did this right.

Here's my sample code where the solution is in bold.

```
<object width="560" height="315"><param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/R9tre2QgzHA?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="//www.youtube.com/v/R9tre2QgzHA?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0&amp;wmode=opaque" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="Opaque"></embed></object>
```

So basically adding wmode="opaque" in the embed src and also adding wmode="Opaque" in one of the attributes of the embed tag solved my problem.

Let me know if this also works for you. If you have better solutions feel free to comment. Thank you very much.